# Скрипт (.bat) для изменения громкости и яркости экрана

Tags: windows, bat, скрипт

Долго думал и не понимал, как возможно такое реализовать. Нужно написать .bat скрипт, который будет принимать два значения (для громкости и для яркости) и , в соответствии , с этими значениями, менять параметры в системе

Comment: думаю можно, скорее всего через правку реестра через скрипт (вот например для яркости https://winaero.com/change-screen-brightness-registry-tweak/) в конечном счете все твики делают правку реестра (в разных версиях могут быть разные ветки)

Answer (score 1):

Для решения вопроса с яркостью:

**bright.bat**

```
powershell $b=%1; (gwmi -n root\wmi -cl WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(0, $b)
```

вызов:

```
bright.bat 100
```

где (`%1` = первый передаваемый аргумент где-то `от 10 до 100`)

Что касается звука то тут немного сложнее, приведенные в том числе на стековерфлоу [скрипты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355891/change-audio-level-from-powershell), мне не удалось запустить (на win7 и win10).

Поэтому рекомендую использовать утилиту [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

Примеры использования:

Максимальное значение 100% = 65535

**50% громкости**

```
nircmd.exe changesysvolume 32768
```

**отключение звука**

```
nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1
```

**включение звука**

```
nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Как правило, это делается внешними утилитами, типа [ControlMyMonitor utility](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/change_monitor_brightness_command_line.html).
Либо [SoundVolumeView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html).

Есть [SO-решение](https://superuser.com/questions/472081/) регулирования яркости ноутбука встроенными средствами.
Так же [SO-решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216334/) для регулировки громкости звука.

Пробуйте, все доступно.